Use custom generated call_id in the Sipp scenarion send Invite instead
I'm using Sipp to run some test cases. In my use case, the Sipp scenario tests a SIP Invite sent to a remote server and validate for 100, 180 and 200 OK finally, a basic uac.xml
The remote end point I'm sending SIP invite using Sipp has some authentication in place where I need to sign the sip invite message headers and those headers include the call_id as well. I know the toAddress and fromAddress used in the Sip invite but is there a way for me to generate the call_id outside the sipp and use it in Sipp Command line argument while invoking the scenario.
I tried to see if there is a way to send a custom call_id from the command line. I could not find a lot of resources around it. The Sipp doc says, this can not be custom generated though, but this is something I need to successfully run my test scenarios.
Doc: https://sipp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scenarios/keywords.html#call-id

Although I could not find the document that says this will work, but the argument cid_str adds the value in the CallId header of the SIP message. Found this from the github issues here: https://github.com/SIPp/sipp/issues/334
I've tested it and it works.
